# How do we solve this insanely sane sequence question?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

This is question from the algebra section of JEE Advanced 2023

---

Let $7 \overbrace{5 \cdots 5}^r 7$ denote the $(r+2)$ digit number where the first and the last digits are 7 and the remaining $r$ digits are 5 . Consider the sum $S=77+757+7557+\cdots+7 \overbrace{5 \cdots 5}^{98}7$. If $S=\frac{7 \overbrace{5 \cdots 5}^{99}7+m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers less than 3000 , then the value of $m+n$ is

---

**MY THINKING**

So my first aim was to calculate the value of S. And my weird intuition made me draw something that is similar to a Pascal's Triangle starting from the last term of S (*I don't know how to draw it here using latex but if anybody could help me by editing thanks!*) which is

.....

$7 \overbrace{5 \cdots 5}^{96}7$

$7 \overbrace{5 \cdots 5}^{97}7$

$7 \overbrace{5 \cdots 5}^{98}7$

So we get an equilateral triangle in the above form and on calculating the sum of the right side of the triangle, we place the unit place's digit as the unit place digit of the value of S and carry over the tenth's and the hundredth's placed digits as remainder on to the summation of the terms of the immediate row parallel to the right side. And then I repeated the process. But something happened in between and I failed in calculating the value of S.

---

Could someone help me on how to efficiently solve this one.

Comment: My first try would be to define $S_r=2+2\cdot 10^{r+1}+5\cdot \frac {10^{r+2}-1}9$ and see if that helps computing $S$

Comment: Is there a city in the US named Dairyland $?$

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Wisconsin

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Are you an Indian student? I noticed the questions in your profile they seem very relevant to JEE exam. I'm a huge fan of, I presume, your country's, exam and has helped me to become a top tier in SAT math

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you Ross, could you tell me the motivation behind thinking like that?

Comment: If I want to add up the numbers I want an expression I can work with algebraically.  These numbers that have patterns in the digits usually have one.  I started with things like $7557=2002+5555$.  The fraction is a handy way of expressing repunits-number like $11111$.  Now you get arithmetic and geometric series that we know how to deal with.

Comment: I have tried fixing your overbraces so they match the JEE examination question. Please make sure these edits were correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the relationship between each term in the sequence and the next. With $a_0 = 77$, we have that

$$a_{r+1} = 10a_r-13$$

This means the difference between each pair of terms is

$$a_{r+1}-a_r = 9a_r - 13$$

Why does this matter? Because we can now chain these incremental differences from $r=99$ all the way down to $r=0$:

$$(a_{99}-a_{98}) + (a_{98}-a_{97}) + \cdots + (a_1-a_0) = (9a_{98}-13) + (9a_{97}-13) + \cdots + (9a_0 - 13)$$

The sum on the left telescopes

$$\require{cancel}(a_{99}-\cancel{a_{98}}) + (\cancel{a_{98}}-\cancel{a_{97}}) + \cdots + (\cancel{a_1}-a_0) = a_{99} - a_0$$

and the sum on the right collects

$$9(a_{98} + a_{97} + \cdots + a_0) - 99\cdot 13 = 9S - 1287$$

which gives us

$$7\overbrace{5\cdots 5}^{99}7 - 77 = 9S - 1287 \implies S = \frac{7\overbrace{5\cdots 5}^{99}7+1210}{9}$$

and therefore the answer is $\boxed{m+n = 1219}$

Answer (score 0):

If you know the method of difference technique then this question is quite doable. If the difference of terms of a series is in AP or GP, then the general term is defined as a polynomial of some degree. In this case the difference is 680 ,6800, 68000, which is a GP with common ratio as 10. The general term is defined as **a(r)^(n-1) + b** where a and b are some constants that we have to find, r is the common ratio, n is the position of term (for eg for the 5th term n = 5)
If you put the value of n = 1 and 2 and solve for a and b you'll get the general term = **680×(10)^(n-1)/81 + 13/9**

Now that you've got the general term just apply the Sigma to get summation of series and n = 100 which will give you the 755...57 (99 times 5) and upon solving you'll get S = (75....57 + 1210)/9
Giving m+n = 1219

Now this might sound like a very long solution but trust me if you are a serious jee aspirant, you won't take much time to find that you have to use method of difference here and once you've figured it out, it's just basic calculations.
Hope it helps.